# Likes count in Node.js Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am building social app having feature of likes, comments, shares. so i have Post model, User model and Like model. So now i want to get all posts with their like, comment count.

I can get all likes of each and every post by this code

in Post Model :

```
PostSchema.virtual('likes', {
    ref: 'Like',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'postId',
});
```

and in post controller :

```
Post.find(query).sort([['updatedAt', 'descending']])
        .populate('postedBy likes', '-__v -hash')
```

And according to mongoose doc [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#count)
we can get count if we use `"count": true` in virtual, but i'm still getting array of likes instead of likes count.

full code of post.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: [true, 'Please enter title']},
    description: {type: String},
    category: {type: String},
    enableNotification: {type: Boolean},
    privacy: {type: String},
    tags: {type: Array},
    coverImage: {type: String},
    media: {type: Array},
    address: {type: String},
    latitude: {type: Number},
    longitude: {type: Number},
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },

}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
});

PostSchema.virtual('likeCount', {
    ref: 'Like',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'postId',
    count: true
});

PostSchema.virtual('likes', {
    ref: 'Like',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'postId',
});

PostSchema.virtual('comments', {
    ref: 'Comment',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'postId',
});

PostSchema.virtual('shares', {
    ref: 'Share',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'postId',
});

PostSchema.index({title: 'text', description: 'text', address: 'text'});

//Export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

here is result of above code

```
{
            "tags": [
                "Ee",
                "Ww",
                "Qq"
            ],
            "media": [
                ""
            ],
            "_id": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
            "postedBy": {
                "_id": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                "name": "Pawneshwer Gupta",
                "email": "learnpainless@gmail.com",
                "socialId": "117121382942158088901",
                "avatar": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Y5Y87PhFToI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AKxrwcblu_UMku61XayTF4z0sMJiD5C8Eg/s96-c/photo.jpg",
                "createdAt": "2019-01-02T16:21:26.035Z",
                "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T07:44:10.399Z",
                "address": "Google Shuttle Stop @ Building 40/43",
                "dob": "2019-01-06T13:14:06.068Z",
                "gender": "Male",
                "latitude": 37.422194600000005,
                "longitude": -122.08336399999999,
                "occupation": "Engineer",
                "zipCode": "140001"
            },
            "title": "Wwww",
            "description": "Ffff",
            "category": "Sports",
            "coverImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onwo-1519446289456.appspot.com/o/5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca%2Fmedia%2FMEDIA_71c79fd0-0b50-11e9-f423-cbfba233f20d.jpg?alt=media&token=0aed8a83-2899-496c-bd24-10e375285146",
            "enableNotification": true,
            "privacy": "Public",
            "createdAt": "2019-01-06T05:26:52.049Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T05:26:52.049Z",
            "likes": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c31b9384821eb66da070b81",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:15:52.747Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:15:52.747Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31b99a4821eb66da070b82",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:17:30.805Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:17:30.805Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31baae4821eb66da070b83",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:22:06.684Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:22:06.684Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31bace4821eb66da070b84",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:22:38.366Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:22:38.366Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31bada4821eb66da070b85",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:22:50.576Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:22:50.576Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31bb6e4821eb66da070b87",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:18.823Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:18.823Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31bb714821eb66da070b88",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:21.930Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:21.930Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31bb824821eb66da070b89",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:38.200Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:38.200Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31bb8d4821eb66da070b8a",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:49.285Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:49.285Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31bb8f4821eb66da070b8b",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:51.560Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:25:51.560Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c31bd8b4821eb66da070b8d",
                    "userId": "5c2ce886ca46ef2765125ecb",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T08:34:19.965Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T08:34:19.965Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c323b624821eb66da070b8e",
                    "userId": "5c2ce506ca46ef2765125eca",
                    "postId": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2",
                    "createdAt": "2019-01-06T17:31:14.062Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T17:31:14.062Z"
                }
            ],
            "comments": [],
            "shares": [],
            "id": "5c31919c598d1440c5af15c2"
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your full model/schema?

Comment: wait updating my question

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: what happens if you populate likesCount instead of likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved this issue by updating version of Mongoose from v5.3.13 to v5.4.3 and now its working fine,
Don't know why it was not working in previous version.
Maybe count variable is not available in that version of Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

This outputs the count as a number:

```
await mongoose.connect(connectionString);
await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

const TextSchema = new Schema({
    testfield: String,
    post: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    },
});

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    locale: String
}, {toObject: { virtuals: true }, timestamps: true});

PostSchema.virtual('posts', {
    ref: 'Text',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'post',
    count: true,
});

let Text = mongoose.model('Text', TextSchema)
let Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)

const newPost = await Post.create({locale: 'something' });

await Text.create([{ testField: 'test', post: newPost   }]);
await Text.create([{ testField: 'test2',post: newPost,  }]);

const posts = await Post.find({})
  .sort([['updatedAt', 'descending']])
  .populate('posts', '-__v -_id')

console.log('POSTS', posts);
```

The output of this is something like this:

```
POSTS { _id: 5c34d47468eb0f373564d4de,
        locale: 'something',
        createdAt: 2019-01-08T16:48:52.007Z,
        updatedAt: 2019-01-08T16:48:52.007Z,
        __v: 0,
        posts: 2,
        id: '5c34d47468eb0f373564d4de' }
```

Comment: yes i m doing the same as i specipied in question, but i m getting object of likeCount instead of likeCount PostSchema.virtual('likeCount', {
    ref: 'Like',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'postId',
    count: true
});

Comment: What version of mongodb and mongoose are you using?

Comment: "mongoose": "^5.3.13","express": "^4.16.4"

Comment: is there any issue in mongoose version?

Comment: No, I think you should be fine. Please create a minimal, standalone demonstration of your problem and post it here.

Comment: i just updated my mongoose version from 5.3.13 to latest version ie. 5.4.3 and problem fixed.

Comment: Ok, this is weird, since virtual population was introduced in 4.5, but maybe the count feature was introduced just recently. Anyways. Please create an answer with your this information and mark it as the right one. Have a nice day!

Comment: yes dont know why this not worked, i wasted my 2 days on this issue :(
yes sure i'll create answer with this info.

Comment: Been there, done that, it happens to the best of us :)

Comment: but count is working for single object type data, if i want to get list of posts with their like count then getting same like count for all item in list. how to resolve this?